# Representation of polar forms corresponding to b-splines

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, spline

Divided differences and polar forms are two elegant tools for the representation of b-splines.
I observed the following connection between both tools.
But, since I didn't find it in the literature yet I believe that it is flawed.
It would be nice if someone could point me to some literature where I can find this observation or show me its flaw.

Let $(x_l)_{l=0,\ldots,n}$  be a knot sequence for a spline of degree $d$  ($x_l\leq x_{l+1}$ , $x_l<x_{l+d+1}$ ).
We assume furthermore $x_l<x_{l+1}$  for $l=d,\ldots,n-d-2$ .

In the following we employ the usual notation

\begin{align*}
(x)_+ :=\begin{cases}
0 &@ x\leq 0\\
x &@ x > 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

and the divided difference

\begin{align*}
[x_0,\ldots,x_d]_x f(x),
\end{align*}

i.e., the highest coefficient of the osculating interpolation polynomial of $f(x)$  with degree $d$ .

The diagonal $M(x,\ldots,x)$  of the multi-variate function

\begin{align*}
  M_l(y_1,\ldots,y_d) := (x_{l+d+1}-x_l)[x_l,\ldots,x_{l+d+1}]_{\bar x} \prod_{m=1}^d (\bar x - y_m)_+
\end{align*}

is the b-spline

\begin{align*}
  b_l(x) &= (x_{l+d+1}-x_l)[x_l,\ldots,x_{l+d+1}]_{\bar x}(\bar x-x)_+^d = M_l(x,\ldots,x).
\end{align*}

Therefore, the diagonal $s(x):=S(x,\ldots,x)$  of

\begin{align*}
S(y_1,\ldots,y_d) &= \sum_{l=0}^{n-d-1} q_l M_l(y_1,\ldots,y_d)
\end{align*}

gives a spline with $q_l\in\mathbb{R}$  ($l=0,\ldots,n-d-1$ ) as degrees of freedom.

We define

\begin{align*}
  (f(x))_{x>y} &:=
\begin{cases}
  0 &@ x < y\\
  f(x) &@ x \geq y
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}

The values of the polar form

\begin{align*}
  P_{l,k}(y_1,\ldots,y_d) := (x_{l+d+1}-x_l)[x_l,\ldots,x_{l+d+1}]_{\bar x} \prod_{m=1}^d (\bar x - y_m)_{\bar x > x_k}
\end{align*}

are equal to $M_l(y_1,\ldots,y_d)$  for arguments $y_i\in [x_k,x_{k+1})$  ($i=1,\ldots,d$ ).

The diagonal $B_k(x,\ldots,x)$  of the polar form

\begin{align*}
  B_k(y_1,\ldots,y_d) &= \sum_{l=0}^{n-d-1} q_l P_{l,k}(y_1,\ldots,y_d)
\end{align*}

equals the spline $s(x)$  for $x\in [x_k,x_{k+1})$ .

Since polar forms are uniquely defined through their diagonal the
$B_k$  should be the same polar forms as described by Lyle Ramshaw in his report ["Blossoms Are Polar Forms"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167839689900320).
(Is that right?)

Therefore, the control values $q_k$  should have the representation

\begin{align*}
q_k = B_k(x_{k+1},\ldots,x_{k+d}).
\end{align*}

Comment: There are many different assertions in your text. Which of them do you think are new?

Comment: @bubba I think none of them is new. I have the impression that most of the statements are trivial. So, they must already exist somewhere in the lit or they must be faulty... The nice aspect of the above representation is that the construction of polar forms from the divided-difference-defined b-spline base functions looks that easy. In the literature I've only found the statement that both methods are equivalent and so they must give the same result. The general construction of polar forms from polynomials is more complicated and not adapted to the special case. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: @bubba Do you see any flaw in the chain of thought? I would be grateful for any comments on that. The most easy solution would be if someone remembers such a representation from some book and just acknowledges it with a reference. But, maybe that one does not read this question:-(. Maybe, it is too trivial to state in a book for most authors? I don't know...